# React Scriptloader creating issues with Enzyme state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

In my react component, I am exporting it using redux with

`export default connect(selector, null)(scriptLoader([https://someurl.com])(JusPayCard));`

I am writing unit tests with jest and enzyme. However my `jusPayCard.state()` doesn't return anything other than 2 props which scriptloader sends while writing tests with enzyme. When I remove script loader export from the component it works. I am using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-async-script-loader for async fetch of a javascript sdk.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I changed my export line to `export default scriptLoader([https://someurl.com])(connect(selector, {})(JusPayCard));`